# What is a solid basic strategy for surviving Ghost Story

Tags: ghost-stories

Is there a solid strategy that you can apply to increase the chances of a win?

Comment: Based on the [Eldritch horror](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/13734/5318) and [Arkham Horror](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/7398/5318) questions.

Comment: 1) Don't let your board fill up.  I'll have to get back to you on 2), because 1) is how my first game ended...

Comment: @PaulMarshall: Most of my games end up with town tiles being haunted because most of the taoists are dead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. When you have the choice, put weak ghosts in the corner spaces. This allows the players the possibility of saving time and killing two ghosts at a time.
2. Use the Buddhas as much as possible. It takes two turns to set them up (with the double-action monk) but automatically kills two ghosts - even big ones that would normally take longer to kill.
3. Only engage with a ghost if you're sure to kill it or only need one die to come up to the appropriate color. If you rely on two dice coming up your way, you will likely be wasting an action that could have been used elsewhere.

Comment: Being a recent player of the game, I would add to this that you should also try to get rid of haunters and tormentors as quickly as possible. This may seem obvious, but if a ghost doesn't have an action that occurs on your turn, there's no urgency to get rid of it unless your board is filling up.